# Understanding resource.xml of ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, network-analyst, xml, internationalization

I want to translate the direction result of network analyst to turkish. I surf in the interent and found i have to change resource.xml file . the file located in arcgis install directory

```
...\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\NetworkAnalyst\Directions
```

I want to find a help file or dictionary file to translate each tag and attribute of the resource.xml file.

For example what does monobranch means in the xml file?

Is there any help file to understand this file?